# Change css value in wordpress site as soon as user logs in

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I’m working on a Worpress site. I’m using the simple-membership plugin to login users. What I want is as soon as a user logs in, an extra primary menu item (the Logout button) at the end should become visible. I changed the visibility in my style.css file in the following manner:

```
.onepress-menu > li:last-child > a {
    padding-right: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

I added the line: display: none;
This made the Logout button disappear.

Now as soon as a user logs in, I want to change the value of display to: display: visible;
How do I accomplish this? I’m not very good in php and that is why I need help. I want the same to happen if a user logs out that the logout menu item disappears again.

Comment: You will not achieve this will CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your theme takes advantage of body_class() in the correct manner then wordpress will automatically apply the class `logged-in` to the body when a user logs in.

So you could do something like:

```
.logged-in .onepress-menu > li:last-child > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped.  Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it worked for you :)